# How do I troubleshoot a certificate chain error? now with code

Tags: java, keystore

I am attempting to use a set of web services from a vendor. I have Java Application code, running out of NetBeans that uses classes from javax.xml to:

1. creates a new Service object based on its URL and QName
2. creates a Dispatch object based on that service object
3. puts a BindingProvider (whatever that is) on the request context from the Dispatch object
4. invokes the dispatch object.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       try
       {
   final Service service 
     = Service.create(new URL("blahblahblah.wsdl"),
                       new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", 
                       "SecurityTokenService")
                      );

   final Dispatch dispatch 
     = service.createDispatch(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", "CustomBinding_IWSTrust13Sync"), 
                               JAXBContext.newInstance("org.oasis_open.docs.ws_sx.ws_trust._200512"), 
                               Mode.PAYLOAD, 
                               new AddressingFeature()
                             );

   final BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) dispatch;

   final Map requestContext = provider.getRequestContext();

   requestContext.put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue");

   final RequestSecurityTokenType request = new RequestSecurityTokenType();

   dispatch.invoke(new JAXBElement<RequestSecurityTokenType>
                         (new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512", "RequestSecurityToken"), 
                           RequestSecurityTokenType.class, 
                           request)
                         );
       }
       catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
   }
   ```

At that point, I get errors in sysout: There are a dozen warnings of the form:

[com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector] selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Trust13" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN"; each such message has a different value in place of "Trust13".

Then I get

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP
>   transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

The vendor provided me with a number of files; three of them seem likely to be security related. I imported both the ".cer" file and a ".p7b" file in the two keystores that I know about ("\users\rcook.keystore" and "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts").

There's a third file which icon might mean it is security related, but when I use KeyStore Explorer (5.1.1) to attempt to open it, KSE says it is cannot be read.

I already have down on my list to get a book on this and learn more about it; in the meantime, where can I look for a solution to the error on this particular program?

Comment: Without seeing the client code that's creating the the request it's going to be difficult to help you.  What your are dealing with most likely here is your web service component is presenting a self signed certificate to the client code and the client code is rejecting it because it cannot trace the cert chain back to an issuer it trusts.  Your options here are to get the server to present a cert your client trusts or alternatively most of these type of clients can be configured to allow an untrusted certificate to be used for TLS/SSL.

Comment: I have no web server component. This is a Java Application, which I did state. I'll edit the post to contain code, though I don't think this is a code problem. But then, I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: You said you were using a set of web services from a vendor so I assumed there was a server component involved.  Regardless of whether the web service is on a server somewhere else or within your application the code is utilizing HTTP to communicate between the requester and the service so I do stand by what I said in my prior comment regarding the fact that the requester code does not trust the certificate presented by the web service component on the TLS handshake.

Comment: Well, I thought a Java application used its trusted keystore to do that; I imported the keys the vendor gave me into the cacerts on that assumption. Was hoping someone could give me a pointer to other things to check; the certificates are both in that store, but other than that I'm not sure what to check.

Comment: There is a difference between a truststore and a keystore.  You know that right?

Comment: I'm not solid on it - thought the truststore (cacerts) was for storing things that I trusted, and a keystore (csi_keystore.jks) was for storing certificates of mine to provide to other places.

Comment: Basically a trust store stores root certificates.  If a certificate presented during TLS handshake can resolve back to a cert in the trust store than the platform trusts it.  A keystore holds your certificates and private keys.  If you want we can chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97553/discussion-between-jjf-and-arcy).

Comment: Here's something interesting: in keystore explorer, if I open one of their keys (has a p7b extension), it shows a 3-step hierarchy -- vend-ROOT-CA, then vend-ISSUING-CA, then vendSecurityToken. Do I need the vend-ISSUING-CA in the keystore, along with the other two?